# Meaning of the phrase "Matter of the very deepest moment"

Tags: meaning

Quoting from "The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes, by Arthur Conan Doyle" -

> “There will call upon you to-night, at a quarter to eight o’clock,” it said, “a gentleman who desires to consult you upon **a matter of the very deepest moment**.

I suspect it means "A matter of grave concern", but I would like to confirm its meaning.

Please share your interpretation of the highlighted phrase.

Comment: Have you looked up 'moment' in a dictionary?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHarvey. I had not. I (incorrectly) assumed that moment is always related to time. According to the Cambridge Dictionary, moment also means "very important".

Answer (score 2):

[moment](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/moment)

> very important:

Related to "momentous."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means a matter of greatest concern.

Comment: This would be better with an explanation and citation.